# How to clean up 123 GB of System Data MacBook Air

Tags: memory, macbook-air

I bought a brand-new MacBook Air in December 2021. I now have over 123 GB of system data. This is ridiculous, considering I have a 256 GB drive, and my apps/documents/developer/ only take up 57 GB.

[See screenshot of system storage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmU51.png)

I am a developer, and I have Xcode, Android Studio, and Visual Studio installed. I wonder if they're filling it up??!? (I doubt it though.)

I looked at MacPaw's CleanMyMacX, and decided I didn't really want to spend $100 on software that may or may not solve my problem.

I've looked and looked around on Google and found some things that did help by approx. 1.5 GB at a time. I am aware of `/Library` and `/System` directories, but I don't want to mess around and break something.

TIA!

Comment: It's probably local Time Machine backups. It will get out of the way if it needs to, or you can flush it by running an external TM backup. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5353/how-can-i-figure-out-whats-slowly-eating-my-drive-space

Comment: I have never used Time Machine...

Comment: You don't need to have - though now would be the time to start, so it will clean up the local copies, which you cannot switch off.

Answer (score 1):

It took me quite a while to find the redundant files on `~/Library/Caches` as mentioned on other guidelines, but it wasn't very helpful. Until I got to know DaisyDisk from this answer: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/253616229?answerId=256789176022#256789176022.
I then deleted a significant amount of extra space. (I'm not DaisyDisk's seller or employees)

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/applehelp/comments/17k432/any_app_like_windirstat_but_for_mac_to_show_what/ or google "windirstat for mac" for more

Comment: @Gantendo nice, thanks!